# Sorting li elements by class? jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, jquery-ui

I have multiple li rows like this

```html
 <ol class="DataList_row"> 

        <li class="Record_row">
            <div class="Item_main">
                <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
                    <div class="status">
                        <span class="Status_offline"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="Record_row">
            <div class="Item_main">
                <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
                    <div class="status">
                        <span class="Status_online"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>  

    </ol>
```

I want to sort all the li rows by the span class "Status_online".
is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean sort by class status_online/status_offline?

Comment: Yes sir thats what i want :)

Comment: Why not sort the data and then present in html?

Comment: If you have pagination, sorting html will be broken.

Comment: Because im not using a manual html its dynamic and li rows creates when a user adds it, so when a user adds a record it goes to the end of the row lists, and what i wan to do is sorting all the list by Status_online class so who ever is online comes to first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

You can use a combination of [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the each `.Record_row` that is an ancestor of each `.Status_online`. Then use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) on each online `.Record_row` and use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.before/) to place them before the first `.Record_row`. In the Snippet notice that each item maintains it's content and ordered from the earliest to the current.

```
$(function() {
  var online = $('.Status_online').closest('.Record_row');
  var first = $('.Record_row')[0];
  online.each(function() {
    $(first).before(this);
  });
});
```

### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sort</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ol class="DataList_row">

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_offline"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>OFFLINE1</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_online"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>ONLINE1</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_offline"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>OFFLINE2</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_online"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>ONLINE2</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_online"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>ONLINE3</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_offline"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>OFFLINE3</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_offline"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>OFFLINE4</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_offline"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>OFFLINE5</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_online"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>ONLINE4</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ol>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    $(function() {
      var online = $('.Status_online').closest('.Record_row');
      var first = $('.Record_row')[0];
      online.each(function() {
        $(first).before(this);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

### OLD

One of your tags is jQuery UI so I'm assuming that you are using it. You can you `.sortable()` method:

```
$('.DataList_row').sortable();
```

This is drag and drop, and I posted before you had commented further details of your need for this sorting to be dynamic...So standby...

### SNIPPET

```js
$('.DataList_row').sortable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ol class="DataList_row"> 

    <li class="Record_row">
        <div class="Item_main">
            <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
                <div class="status">
                    <span class="Status_offline"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>OFFLINE</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
        <div class="Item_main">
            <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
                <div class="status">
                    <span class="Status_online"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>ONLINE</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>  

</ol>
```

Comment: That works fine but Sorry i do not want drag and drop i want a simple sort by Online class name automatically :/

Comment: Worked perfect :P Thats exactly what i wanted Thanks a bunch brother :)

Comment: Great, I'm happy hear that. :)

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sort</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ol class="DataList_row">

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_offline"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>OFFLINE1</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_online"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>ONLINE1</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_offline"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>OFFLINE2</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_online"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>ONLINE2</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_online"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>ONLINE3</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_offline"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>OFFLINE3</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_offline"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>OFFLINE4</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_offline"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>OFFLINE5</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Record_row">
      <div class="Item_main">
        <a href="#" class="arrow_box">
          <div class="status">
            <span class="Status_online"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>ONLINE4</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ol>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    $(function() {
var olElement = $('.DataList_row');
var sortedAttributes = $('.status span').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).sort(); //This returns all the class statuses
console.log(sortedAttributes);
olElement.empty(); //Remove all li elements
var liHtml = '';
$(sortedAttributes).each(function(idx, cl){
var clClass = cl.startsWith('ONLINE')?'online':'offline'
liHtml += '<li class="Record_row"><div class="Item_main"><a href="#" class="arrow_box"><div class="status"><span class="Status_' + clClass + '"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>' + cl + '</span></div></a></div></li>';
});
olElement.append(liHtml); //Re-add all the elements that are sorted.
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is how you can do it:

```
var olElement = $('.DataList_Row');
var sortedAttributes = $('.status span').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).sort(); //This returns all the class statuses

olElement.empty(); //Remove all li elements
var liHtml = ''; 
$(sortedAttributes).each(function(idx, cl){
    liHtml += '<li class="Record_row"><div class="Item_main"><a href="#" class="arrow_box"><div class="status"><span class="Status_' + cl.toLowerCase() + '"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>' + cl + '</span></div></a></div></li>'; 
});
olElement.append(liHtml); //Re-add all the elements that are sorted.
```

Comment: could you please provide me a jsfiddle or codepen link? i try but it does not work